# Accessing a value in an embedded document in an array

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, aggregation-framework

Consider a document containing an array of embedded documents:

```
{'array': [{'key1': 120.0, 'key2': 69.0}, {'key1': 100.0, 'key2': 50.0}]}
```

I want to project `key2` for the first element of the array.

I naively tried

```
'$project':
    {
        'item': '$array.0.key2'
    }
```

which fails (but explains what I want to do better than many words).

#### Using $arrayElemAt and $let

Since MongoDB 3.2, it is possible to get an item from the list using [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/#exp._S_arrayElemAt):

```
'$project':
    {
        'item1': {'$arrayElemAt': ['$array', 0] }
    }
```

will return `item1` as `{'key1': 120.0, 'key2': 69.0}`.

What I want `key2` in there.

I managed to get it using [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/#exp._S_let):

```
'$project':
    {
        'item': {
            '$let': {
                'vars': {
                    'tmp': {'$arrayElemAt': ['$array', 0] },
                    },
                'in': '$$tmp.key2'
            }
        },
    }
```

#### Is there a simpler way?

This seems painfully verbose. Especially considering I'd like to use this construction in several expressions for the same value (test not zero, then use in division) in the same projection.

#### The context

The array stores the successive states of the object represented in the document, sorted by date, reverse order. The 1st element of the array is the last (therefore current) state. I want to sort the documents using a ratio of two values in the current state.

It is possible that the only reasonable solution would be to get the last state out of the array. Or even to pre-calculate the ratio and sort on the pre-calculated value.

Comment: Please show sample document with the expected output. You should also explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: I provided a simplified example (2nd line of question). The documents contain an array of embedded documents. I want to sort all documents according to a specific field in the first element of the array (`array.0.key2`). I [minimized](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) the example for the question. Should I provide a more complete real-life example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an aggregation pipeline you can repeat steps to keep things cleaner so after:

```
'$project': {'item1': {'$arrayElemAt': ['$array', 0] }}
```

you can add:

```
{$project: {"item1.key2": 1}}
```

Comment: Useful tip. What if I want to project a dozen fields from the document ? I'll have to specify all of them at each projection stage, right ? (I can edit my OP if this comment is unclear.)

Comment: Yes, you are correct. That is a lot of fields to type but it is the way to do it.

Comment: @user3100115, Tiramisu, I was trying to get item1.key2 in the first projection, but only getting item1 then accessing key2 on a subsequent pipeline step makes it much easier and clearer in my code so I'll go for this. It looks like the best way. Thank you both.

Comment: Starting in 3.4 you could also just use $addFields instead of $project, which lets you add new fields without having to redefine the old ones. If you specify a field that already exists it'll overwrite it

Answer (score 2):

Actually you don't need to use the [`$let`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) operator to do this. Simply use the [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) operator in your [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage to return the first item in your "array" and the [`$$ROOT`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT) system variable to return the current document. From there you can easily  specify the field to [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) by using the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation). Additionally you can add another `$project` stage to the pipeline to discard the "item" field and the  "_id" field from the query result.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": { 
        "item": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$array", 0 ] },  
        "doc": "$$ROOT"
    }}, 
    { "$sort": { "item.key2": 1 } }, 
    { "$project": { "doc": 1, "_id": 0 } }
])
```